# How return array of arrays in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have module like this in node js

```
var types =  function (){

  var typeList= new Array();
  typeList[0] = "varchar";

  var numericDTs= new Array();
  numericDTs[0] = "tinyint";

  var binaryDTs= new Array();
  binaryDTs[0] = "tinyblob";

  var data = array();
  data[0] = typeList;
  data[1] = numericDTs;
  data[2] = binaryDTs;

  return data;
}

module.exports = {
  types: types,
}
```

i am calling this module like this

```
var types = require("./include/types");
console.log(types.types());
```

i got error like this
**500 ReferenceError: array is not defined**
no error if i return only types or typeList or binaryDTs.
How return array of arrays in node js?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
var data = array();
```

Write the following instead:

```
var date = [];
```

Actually replace every `new Array()` with `[]`.

Instead of

```
var typeList= new Array();
typeList[0] = "varchar";
```

write `var typeList = [ "varchar" ];` and so on.

**EDIT:**

Actually your whole function can be reduced to:

```
var types = function() {
     return [ [ "varchar" ], [ "tinyint" ], [ "tinyblob" ] ];
};
```

Comment: Ah... after your last edit, my update seems much more minor than it was intended to be :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak: Thx, I edited that. I also upvoted your answer as it is a even shorter solution.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on the other answer,

assuming you don't use the function anywhere else, you could just write

```
 module.exports = {
   types: function(){
     return [["varchar"], ["tinyint"], ["tinyblob"]];
   }
 }
```